# i tried to create a table. But the letters are running out of column. let me know y

Tags: tables

[image: somebody plz help me to create a table like this. its going out of column.]

this was the code which i used:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | 4 | 4 | 4 | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    Sr. no & Context in Use/Dataset & Techniques & Key Points
 +Pros and – Cons
 \\hline

    1 & For splice site recognisation in DNA Sequences  & Support vector
Machine(SVM)
 & +It performs better result for \nbegin identifying the Splice sites.
-It needs appropriate kernel function for training the data otherwise leads to poor classification.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't use `4` as a column specification (what do you intend it to do?) `! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.` and `\nbegin` is not defined: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.14  & +It performs better result for \nbegin`

Comment: Sir, can you edit the code?

Comment: @Carlisle: Sir, I'm a beginner

Comment: Yes but if you get an error message you should ask about that. there is no poit asking about the _output_ after an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't really mention what you were expecting in the column declarations, I edited your code as follow. I also add a line break between your pros and cons in the first line of data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{6cm} |}
    \hline
    Sr. no & Context in Use/Dataset & Techniques & Key Points +Pros and – Cons \\ \hline
    1 & For splice site recognisation in DNA Sequences  & Support vector Machine(SVM) & +It performs better result for begin identifying the Splice sites.\newline -It needs appropriate kernel function for training the data otherwise leads to poor classification. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning.  Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Another mistake in your code was the `\\hline` after the first line of data, that is not correct, I replaced it with `\\ \hline`.

A last mistake was the `\nbegin` that I deleted.

Also note that you can condense the columns spec by replacing `| p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{6cm} |` with `*{3}{|p{2cm}} | p{6cm} |` as the first three columns are here expected to have the same description.

I hope it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You could a `tabularx` environment, set to the width of the textblock, with automatic line wrapping enabled for columns 2, 3, and 4. In the example below, I use a modified version of the `X` column type to use ragged-right typesetting instead of full justification for material in the narrow columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l | L | L | L |}
\hline
Sr.\ no & Context in Use\slash Dataset & Techniques 
        & Key Points, $+$~Pros and $-$~Cons\\
\hline

1 & For splice site recognition in DNA Sequences  
  & Support vector Machine (SVM)
  & $+$ It performs better result for identifying the Splice sites.\\
  & & & 
  $-$ It needs appropriate kernel function for training the data otherwise leads to poor classification. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ 
\hline
Tue. & 9C & 19C 
     & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ 
\hline
Wed. & 10C & 21C 
     & Rain will still linger for the morning. Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue throughout the evening. \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```